# Meaning of "GHES: HEST is not enabled!" in dmesg

Tags: linux, dmesg

After reboot of a SuSE 12 host I looked into `dmesg` and came across the info

```
    GHES: HEST is not enabled!
```

GHES obviously means "APEI Generic Hardware Error Source support". 
Should GHES/HEST be enabled? What about the benefit of it? How to achieve this, if it is advisable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have several SLES machines in production and never used this. Here's a good overview: https://firmware.intel.com/sites/default/files/resources/A_Tour_beyond_BIOS_Implementing_APEI_with_UEFI_White_Paper.pdf

> Hardware Error Source Table (HEST) The HEST table enables host
>   firmware to declare all errors that platform component can generate
>   and error signaling for those. The host firmware shall create Error
>   source entries in HEST for each component (such as, processor, PCIe
>   device, PCIe bridge, etc) and each type of error with corresponding
>   error notification mechanism (singling) to OS. These error entries
>   include x86 architectural errors, industry standard errors and generic
>   hardware error source for platform errors. The x86 architectural
>   errors, MCE and CMC, and standard errors PCIe AER, MSI and PCI INTx
>   can be handled by OS natively. The generic hardware error source can
>   be used for all firmware 1st errors and platform errors (such as
>   memory, board logic) that do not have OS native signaling, so they
>   have to use platform signaling SCI or NMI.

I guess if you really want to monitor all the hardware errors this might be useful.

Comment: Very useful definition, which makes things quite clear.

Comment: Link is broken, [fixed link](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/download/a-tour-beyond-bios-implementing-the-acpi-platform-error-interface-with-the-uefi.html)